# Why am I getting a 403 (Forbidden) error when I make a second Rest API call?

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am getting data from the discogs API. It works fine when I get a single page of results, but when I try and make a second call (to get the next page of results) I get a 403 (Forbidden) error.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())        
{
  wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "myUserName");
  var json = wc.DownloadString(String.Format("https://api.discogs.com/users/{0}/collection/folders/0/releases", username));    
  var json2 = wc.DownloadString(String.Format("https://api.discogs.com/users/{0}/collection/folders/0/releases?page=2", username));
}
```

Is this something to do with making two calls in the same `using (WebClient...)` block, or some other authentication issue?

Comment: Put them in two separate calls, what happens?

Comment: I'm surprised you can even call it once by adding that header alone, I'd expect it to be ignored. Are you authenticating with a key and haven't posted details about it?

Comment: Hmmm - if I split it into two separate calls, it works. Don't think it's rate related, maybe it gets upset if you make two calls from the same web client?

Comment: You shouldn't really be using WebClient anyway, use HttpClient instead, it's far more modern and well supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers in `WebClient` are cleared after each call so you would need to re-add them, for example:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())        
{
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "myUserName");
    var json = wc.DownloadString(String.Format("https://api.discogs.com/users/{0}/collection/folders/0/releases", username));    

    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "myUserName");
    var json2 = wc.DownloadString(String.Format("https://api.discogs.com/users/{0}/collection/folders/0/releases?page=2", username));
}
```

However, you should really consider using the newer, modern `HttpClient` instead. Even the [docs for `WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) state:

> We don't recommend that you use the `WebClient` class for new development. Instead, use the [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Comment: You, sir, are a bona fide legend!!

Comment: @ibubi Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Noted re HttpClient, too - thanks, will move it to that.